# Why does my javascript only retrieve one input elements value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, field

I'm trying to retrieve values from elements from a form. But for some reason I can only get the value from one element.

This is my html code:

```
<form name="registerform" class="registerform">
        <label for="usernamefield">Username: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="field" id="usernamefield"></input>
        <br>
        <label for="emailfield">Email: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="email" name="emailfield" id="emailfield"></input>
        <br>
        <label for="passwordfield">Password: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="passwordfield" id="passwordfield"></input>
        <br>
        <label for="passwordrepeatfield">Repeat Password: </label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="passwordrepeatfield"></input>
        <br>
        <!--Check field-->
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="agreementbox" id="agreementbox"></input>
        <label for="agreementbox" id="termslink">I agree to the </label>
        <a href="" id="termslink">terms</a>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="registerbutton" value="Register" onclick="registerUser()">

    </form>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
function registerUser()
{

var username = document.getElementById("usernamefield").value;
var email = document.getElementById("emailfield").value;
var password = document.getElementById("passwordfield").value;

console.log("Username: " + username);
console.log("Email: " + email);
console.log("Password: " + password);

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    // Code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("POST",
             "RegisterUser.php?username=" + username
             + "&email=" + email
             + "&password" + password,
             true);
xmlhttp.send();


}
```

In the console I only see the value, that is typed into the email field.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Made a JSBin for it, and it seems to work fine: http://jsbin.com/upiZayi/1/edit.

Comment: input type="field"? shouldn't this be 'text' or something?

Comment: Yes, see for valid input types http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: @matti http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up on input types

I figured out the problem. Apparently I managed to have duplicate input elements with the same id.

Thanks to everyone for your help :)